# Order by both Parent and then Child using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to order a collection of parent objects by both a parent's property and a child's property?

Let's say I have an Entity class that has this bit of code:

```
@OrderBy("age")
public List<Father> getFathers() {
    return fathers;
}
```

The Father Entity has an age property which we want to order by ascending age (as shown above).

A Father can have a Child.  A Child would also have an age property.  I would like `getFathers()` to return a Fathers list such that they are ordered by the Fathers' age and then subsequently the Child's age ascending.

If I keep the code above as is, the Fathers would be ordered by their own age correctly but a Father (aged 30) with a 10 year old Child could come before a Father (also aged 30) with a 5 year old Child.

I tried doing something like this:

```
@OrderBy("age, child.age")
public List<Father> getFathers() {
    return fathers;
}
```

But I would get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: property from @OrderBy clause not found: Father.child.age
```

**Edit:** Sorry, let me clarify with a bit more code.  The `getFathers()` is not in the Child entity but in another entity.  Let's call it Village:

```
@Entity
public class Village {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "village",
               targetEntity = Father.class)
    @OrderBy("age")
    public List<Father> getFathers() {
        return fathers;
    }
}
```

So let's say there is a Village and you can obtain the Fathers that live in this Village.  For this example's sake, let's say that a Father for some odd Village rule can only have one child each.

So Father would look something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Father {
    private Child child;
    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "father")
    public Child getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
}
```

So now in the original Village class, I want `getFathers()` to return all the fathers in order of age, plus, if there are any fathers with the same age, I want them to be then ordered by the age of their child.

**Edit 2:** I've also found that I can get the effect of what I want however it can't be the most elegant way of doing it:

```
session.createFilter(village.getFathers(), "order by child.age");
```

Comment: Show both of your classes with the properties in question mapped. Please omit other properties for brevity.

Comment: Of course! You can do it using `Filter`, but you need a `child` property in `Father` class anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are missing two-way mapping. You should also map `Child` in `Father`.

By the way, there should be one-to-many relationship between `Father` and `Child`, traditionally speaking. Which means in `Father` class there should be a `List<Child> children;` property, and not the other way around.

**[EDIT]**

No, you can't do like that. Why? Because when you define your `@OrderBy("age, child.age")`, the whole of it, `child.age`, would be considered as a property. It will be treated as a `String`. Hence, indeed, you don't have any property name `child.age` in `Father` class. I hope you are getting my point. So, the `Filter` solution, you came up with, is a good way to go.

Comment: My Father class always had the Child property and still causes the Order By exception.

Comment: @digiarnie: No, you can't do like that. Why? Because when you define your `@OrderBy("age, child.age")`, the whole of it, `child.age`, would be considered as a property. It will be treated as a `String`. Hence, indeed, you don't have any property name `child.age` in `Father` class. I hope you are getting me. So, the `Filter` solution is a good way to go.